# Movable Navigation at the bottom which stays there at window resize

Tags: html, css, web

I want to make myself a little website and I'm almost completely new to this world (did some stuff in school and know how to make a basic page, but nothing special). I wanted to ask you how to make a movable navigation at the bottom which stays there at window resize.

I tried it by myself already, but since I use bootstrap and materializecss I think I wrote some useless lines in the css and can't really show what I've done so far. I tried something with absolute positioning, but it screwed over when people turn off the chrome browser bookmark bar, so I switched back to relative.

Long story short, I really want to have a navbar like on this website: http://www.reverse-magazine.com/

Comment: Navbar is the navigation bar at the top, did you mean footer?

Comment: Don't be anxious about showing us what you tried - we all learn faster that way.

Comment: @Ctc nope take a look at the linked website .. the navigation is at the bottom at first but if you scroll down it moves and stays at the top ... i did the same but when i resize the window the bar is too far down since i used relative positioining

Comment: Oh.. this is reletively easy, upload your code and ill see what have you done and suggest a good edit :)

Comment: @K.Menyah i would like to show it to you but since i used marterialize and bootstrap i cant post a complete jsfiddle here ... i mean bootstrap is too long to use there :D i will upload it now to a webspace so maybe you find the mistake just wait a moment :P

Comment: @Ctc ye cant upload my code since i used bootstrap withits giant css so i uploaded all i have to my webspace: http://penguin.square7.ch/

Comment: @K.Menyah http://penguin.square7.ch/ here you go thats what i got so far

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you going:

https://jsfiddle.net/f26eudd7/2/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var navbar_el = $('.navbar');
  var navbar_top = navbar_el.offset().top;
  
  $(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > navbar_top) {
      navbar_el.addClass('sticky');
    } else {
      navbar_el.removeClass('sticky');
    }
  });
  
  $(window).resize(function() {
    navbar_top = navbar_el.offset().top;
  });
});
```

```css
html,body { 
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

.full-height {
  height: 100%
}

header {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  background-image: url('http://placehold.it/1920x1080');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center; 
}

.navbar {
  background: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 65px;
}

.navbar.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 100;
}

#content {
  background: #ff0000;
  height: 1000px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header class="full-height">
  <nav class="navbar">
    Your navbar
  </nav>
</header>

<div id="content">
  Your content
</div>
```

Comment: Good answer, done in a way that OP should be able to understand

Comment: omg thank you so much that works exactly how i wanted. sadly i know nothing about java script so you helped me alot.

Comment: one more thing: when the navbar "sticks" to the top the "your content"-text is behind it. is it possible to tell the site that it should under the navigation? i could need it for hashlinks since it always scrolls too far. i tried paddings and margins but nothing seemed to work (repost..i thought i need to link your name im new to this side sry :))

Comment: Glad I could help! The trick is to add padding and negative margin. You could do something like this: https://jsfiddle.net/f26eudd7/3/

Comment: wow i tried to understand this "positive padding and negative margin" and almost forgot to thank you again :D .. well i still dont really know why this works but i see how this works and thats all i need i guess. thanks again.

Comment: oh right one thing before i stop to "annoy" you. what do i have to change if i want the "header" (how do you called it) to be fixed. so the navigation and the content scoll over it (like i usually planned to do http://penguin.square7.ch). if you cant do it without to much work its ok i can let it scroll .. thought i'd be a cool "feature"

Comment: No problem - just add `background-attachment: fixed;` to the header CSS and it should work.

If this was of any help to you I would appreciate it if you mark my answer as accepted ;)

Comment: ofc i will mark your answer as accepted when i find out how to do this :D

  one little thing :D .. i added your answer to my new started code but the sticky thing still doesnt work :( https://jsfiddle.net/1kh9uubm/ i copied everything the way you wrote it (i "out-commented" the marterialize and bootstrap stuff so i guess its not its fault)

Comment: The JS stops working because `sideNav()` is not declared. If you comment out this part (line 3-8) you'll see that it's working. That's the way JS works - one error and the scripts stops at this point.

Comment: oh ok nice thanks :D .. like i already said .. im a completely "noob" in this whole programming/webdesigning world. you saved my day.